# ios UIPanGestureRecognizer pointer position

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSLog(@"%f", [gesture translationInView:self].x);
}
```

The above code will log the relative position of my current pan, but how can I get the absolute position for the view I'm in?

I'm simply just wanting to slide a `UIImageView` to wherever the user's finger is.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the absolute position for the view I'm in"*?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`translationInView` gives you the pan translation (how much x has changed) and not the position of the pan in the view (the value of x). If you need the position of the pan, you have to use the method `locationInView`.

You can find the coordinates relatively to the view as follows:

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSLog(@"%f", [gesture locationInView:self].x);
}
```

Or relatively to the superview:

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSLog(@"%f", [gesture locationInView:self.superview].x);
}
```

Or relatively to the window:

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    NSLog(@"%f", [gesture locationInView:self.window].x);
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use `UIGestureRecognizer`'s `view` property instead of `self`? It allows you to move the gesture recognizer around without breaking things. Also for window location, it's sufficient to pass `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

Use the method `.location()` that returns a `CGPoint` value. [[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624219-location)]

For example, relative location of your gesture to `self.view`:

```
let relativeLocation = gesture.location(self.view)
print(relativeLocation.x)
print(relativeLocation.y)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can post the proper call for getting absolute/non-relative location within the window or view? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple way of something like this is to get the x and y of the touch and tracking it, once it has 2 points (say X:230 Y:122) you set the scroll of the UIScroll view to the x and y.